# Placing an ImageView at the specific coordinates of another ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, coordinates, android-imageview

Hello I'm looking for a solution to a problem I'm having, in Android Is there any way of placing one ImageView at specified coordinates on another ImageView? 
For example, get specific coordinates of ImageView A (lets say dead center), then place ImageView B on the coordinates of ImageView A. Causing ImageView B to be placed dead center in the middle of ImageView B. Then allowing me to change around the coords to move ImageView B around within ImageView A.
Apologies if i've written this in a confusing way

Comment: use this https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable

Comment: have try any things from your end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to use a `RelativeLayout` to align the top left corners of the two and then use `padding` to offset the top one. So to put `im2` on `im1` at x=20, y=15:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/+im1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/+im2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/im1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/im1"
        android:paddingTop="15px"
        android:paddingLeft="20px" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can update padding from code via [`ImageView.setPadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

You can try the same with margins, but messing with margins from code is hard.

*There's also a long-deprecated [`AbsoluteLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), but I don't suggest the use of that, it may be easier to create your own layout manager, it's not that hard, that can encapsulate the code of calculating the offset you one nicely.*

**Edit:**
With the above (padding or probably margin if you need to go negative) you can move the image around and still letting the x/y calculated by a layout.

If you want to dead center both images just add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to both in a `RelativeLayout`.

Though if you want to move it around I'd suggest using a canvas to draw your "actors" on it, then set the canvas to display in a single `ImageView`; or instaed of the canvas use a suggested library in the question's comments.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but why the padding? The question was how to set the exact same coordinates, but using padding will offset one view in relation to the other.

Comment: Thats a good solution. I was hoping of a way of doing it programmatically

Comment: I suppose .setPadding would be a way of setting where the second imageview appears through code

Comment: Updated, if you want to program, use a `Canvas`, that's the most flexible.

Comment: So the best solution here might be to use a canvas?

Comment: Yes I suggest you try that route instead of trying to force layouts and views to do it for you. I suppose you have a background (big ImageView) and an actor (small ImageView on top, initially in the middle) and you want to move the actor around based on user input/sensor.